# What is the combinatoric explain of the equation $4{51 \choose 12}={52 \choose 13}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

I don't know how to explain the combinatoric meaning of the expression $4{51 \choose 12} = {52 \choose 13}$. I want a explain using cards desk? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So suppose you want to choose $13$ cards out of $52$, this is normally done in $\binom{52}{13}$ ways.

Then, you fix one card , which is done in $52$ ways, and then choose $12$ cards out of the remaining $51$. This can be done in $52\binom{51}{12}$ ways. But, we have to divide by $13$, and the reason is this: in the end, we end in a collection of cards. Call these cards from card $1$ to card $13$.

See that, if I had picked card $1$ first, and then while picking $12$ cards, picked up the cards $2,3,4,...,13$, then my final collection is $1,2,...,13$.

But, it's also possible that I picked card $2$ first, and then while picking $12$ cards, picked up the cards $1,3,4,...,13$, then my final collection is again $1,2,...,13$.

But, it's also possible that I picked card $8$ first, and then while picking $12$ cards, picked up the cards $1,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13$, then my final collection is again $1,2,...,13$.

Do you see what I am hinting at? The same collection is generated $13$ times using our previous algorithm, because each one of the elements in the collection could have been the first card. Hence, we have to divide by $13$, because all these cases are resulting in the same collection.

Hence, $\binom{52}{13} = 52\binom{51}{12} \div 13 = 4\binom{51}{12}$.

I hope this was clear.

Comment: It'd be interesting to know if one could use $4$ more directly instead of $\frac{52}{13}$. Such as: Pick 12 cards out of 51 cards (say, we removed the ace of spades). Then flip two coins and use some algorithm to arrive at 13 cards (with the ace of spades allowed again) from these inputs. But it seems hard to come up with an algorith mthat is not awfully involved.

Comment: Whoever up voted me, did I  do the right thing? Or should I have given the interpretation of the  result , like the other answers have done?

Comment: Thank you very much, it's easy to understand.

Comment: You are welcome, @ndakostan

Comment: So if my interpretation is: the left hand side, choose an ace, so we have $4$ ways to choose ace. Then choose ${51\choose 12}$ remaining card. So we have a way to choose ${52 \choose 13}$ cards. Is is true.

Comment: @ndakostan No, because then you are assuming that every choice of cards contains an ace, which is not true.

Comment: So maybe the true equation for my above interpretation is $4{51\choose 12} + {48\choose 13}={52\choose 13}$ which ${48\choose 13}$ is the number of ways our choice of cards does not contain ace?

Comment: Overcounting occurs here also . Suppose you choose the ace of spades first, then ace of hearts while choosing $12$ cards. You could get the same collection, if you fixed the ace of hearts first, and then chose the ace of spades along with the $12 $ cards. Thus, over counting is happening in cases where there are more than two aces in your collection of 13 cards.

Answer (score 3):

If you are dealt $13$ cards the probability that the ace of hearts is among them is ${1\over4}\>$.

Comment: This is a very nice interpretation. Is there an obvious reason why this probability should be $\frac{1}{4}$ (I mean not using this binomial identity) ?

Comment: So if I'm dealt 13 cards, which probability that the $13th$ is an ace.

Comment: I think if we split the desk into $4$ partitions, then the probability that ace of hearts in the first partition (the partition dealt to us) is $\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

You may interpret it as $4  = \frac{52}{13}$, and use the identity

$$k\binom{n}{k} = n \binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

Which can be explained in that way : the left-hand-side is counting the ways to pick $k$ elements out of $n$ and chosing a special element among them. The right-hand-side is picking the special element first, and the $k-1$ others afterwards, among the $n-1$ remaining.

Comment: You meant to write $\binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$ on the RHS.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig : I most certainly did, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Thank you very much. It's a nice interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

It means there is four times more ways to pick $13$ cards from a deck of $52$, than to pick $12$ cards from a deck of $51$.

Comment: While this answer is technically true, I don't think that's what the OP is after. Questions like these are often looking for explanations of the kind "count the same set of combinations in two different ways to get equality". I might be wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can have $\binom{52}{13}$ possible hands.
Divide the cards into lots of $4$. In each round, you could get any of the $4$.

Imagine that you are dealt last, and that $12$ cards each have been dealt. When they finally come to you, $51$ cards have been dealt,  **but you could get any of the last 4** to complete your hand.

Thus $4\binom{51}{12} = \binom{52}{13}$